# Android Facebook GraphResponse get string from an array

Tags: android, arrays, facebook

I'm getting confused on everything I'm reading through.  I'm trying to get the specific items from an array so I can show them on in a view.

I'm using Facebook's GraphResponse to pull IDs, Names, AccessTokens, etc. But I don't know how to use `getJSONArray()` or `getJSONObject()` or even when to use either.

I have this request:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
    accessToken,
    "/me/accounts",
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            // Insert your code here
        }
});

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "name,id,access_token");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

which should yield me this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Sample Page 1",
            "id": "1234567890",
            "access_token": "sample_token"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sample Page 2",
            "id": "2234567890",
            "access_token": "sample_token"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sample Page 3",
            "id": "3234567890",
            "access_token": "sample_token"
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "before": "***********",
            "after": "***********"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'm having a problem with the "your code here" part.  I've been experimenting with `for` loops after making the `response` into an array, but I don't know how to get each string for each page in the data.

I've tried playing around with this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray();
for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
    //Not sure what goes in here to get the string of "name" or "access_token
}
```

I'd like to know how to get information from an array inside of GraphRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how:

```
GraphRequest requestPage = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
    currentAccessToken,
    "/me/accounts",
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            try {
                jsonArray = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
                for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject page = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String pageName = page.getString("name");
                    String pageToken = page.getString("access_token");
                    Log.d("************", ""+pageName+" "+pageToken);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    Bundle parametersPages = new Bundle();
    parametersPages.putString("fields", "name,access_token");
    requestPage.setParameters(parametersPages);
    requestPage.executeAsync();
```